# Ionic project throws exception when run on android?

Tags: android, cordova, ionic-framework

I'm trying execute an Ionic project on Android. When I try execute the project does throws an exception from cordova. Looking for a solution I found some peoples saying to set path of Android SDK, I made this but I still haven't any success. I added paths `C:\Users\fernando\AppData\Local\Android\sdk\tools` and `C:\Users\fernando\AppData\Local\Android\sdk\platform-tools`.

How could I solve it ?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

1. Check your path of Android with `ANDROID_HOME` variable. This path should be the root of your SDK in the `User variables`. If it is not exist, add a new one.

   - Type `$ android` in the command line to check the SDK.
   - You also have to check if the `API 19` has been installed.
2. Try to un-plug the device and re-plug again. Run the `adb devices` to make sure your device has been recognized by the computer.